# Matlab programming while writing a code for iris detection

Tags: matlab

```
    I=imread('C:\Users\stariqp\Desktop\c5.jpg');
    rmin=100;
    rmax=400;
```

These are the inputs to my function below which i give in the command window and when i call my function, there is an error " Input argument "rmin" is undefined." The function is the first line in the .m file.

```
   function [ci,cp,out]=thresh(I,rmin,rmax)
```

Comment: where is the body of that function. Also, write the entire function in a separate m-file and then call it from the main file (where you read the image etc.) as: `[ci,cp,out]=thresh(I,rmin,rmax)`.

Answer (score 0):

save the function into a separate file called `thresh.m`. Then in your main function, run

```
I=imread('C:\Users\stariqp\Desktop\c5.jpg');
rmin=100;
rmax=400;
[ci,cp,out]=thresh(I,rmin,rmax)
```

Comment: is the error in thresh.m? it will show you which line in the thresh.m causes the error

Comment: I=imread('C:\Users\stariqp\Desktop\c5.jpg');
rmin=100;
rmax=400;
[ci,cp,out]=thresh(I,rmin,rmax)                                        Now what i am doing is, i run these four lines in another .m file and the function is in thresh.m. error appears in thresh.m that "Function definitions are not permitted in this context."

Comment: I don't have the error you got.It looks good to me. Make sure you include search.m and partiald.m in the same directory of your main file and thresh.m. And don't name your main file the same name as thresh.m

Comment: Yes the error disappeared and the program was running fine after some time, Thanks a lot for helping